# Selectively update dataframe column with a dictionary map

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use a dictionary to map / replace row values in a pandas column - but only for a subset of rows based on a criteria

```
df['var'] = df['var'].map(mydict)
```

but only where

```
df['anothervar'] is somevalue
```

Can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with `np.where`

```
df['var'] = np.where(df['anothervar']=='somevalue',df['var'].map(mydict),df['var'])
```